# How do I detect content type of POST payload if Content-Type not specified?

Tags: node.js, express, content-type

I have an express-based server running and it's using bodyParser.json() and bodyParser.text() added to the pipeline. Now, some consumers make a POST request to this server's endpoints with JSON payload, but without specifying `content-type:application/json' in the request header. That leads to the body of the request to be ignored by bodyParser and hence not included into response.

```
--- client --- 
fetch('http://myurl/submit', {method: 'POST', body: "{key: value}"}, cb);

--- server ---
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
    // req.body - IS EMPTY!!!
    // I assume it's empty because bodyParser.json() didn't recognise the payload as json as no content-type header was included
})
```

Question: in my express app, how can I detect the content type of POST body if none is provided? Are there standard libraries that would accept the body content and return its mime type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bodyParser docs on :https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

> bodyParser.json([options])
>
> Returns middleware that only parses json and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
>
> Options
>
> The json function takes an optional options object that may contain any of the following keys:
>
> strict
>
> When set to true, will only accept arrays and objects; when false will accept anything JSON.parse accepts. Defaults to true.

Maybe setting strict to false will help you.